# Remove [html]any_string[/html] from content

Tags: regex

What is the best regular expression to remove this string from content?

```
[html]any_string[/html]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks very simple:

```
\[html\].*?\[\/html\]
```

Explanation:

`.*?` (Any character "**.**" 0 or more times "*****" and ungreedy "**?**"

[Example in PHP](http://xrg.es/#q9knto)

Comment: What does ungreedy mean in this context?

Comment: @Nick Just to make sure that .* will not include [/html]. Imagine a String with that pattern twice.. see this example with greedy. http://xrg.es/#3y07vs